# Fatal exception main - Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, illegalargumentexception, google-mlkit

In my app, I am analysing an image that is cropped, and detecting if it has text or not. This is the code of the icon that triggers the camera.

```
Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.oval), contentDescription = null,
                    tint = Color.White,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(100.dp)
                        .padding(16.dp)
                        .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                        .clickableWithoutRipple(interactionSource) {
                            if (!imageInProcess.value){
                                coroutineScope.launch {

                                    viewModel.loadingCircleShown()
                                    imageInProcess.value = true

                                    val imageFile =
                                        imageCaptureUseCase.takePicture(currentContext.executor)
                                    onImageFile(imageFile)

                                    imageUri = imageFile.toUri()
                                    if (imageUri != emptyImageUri) {

                                        val cropOptions = CropImageContractOptions(imageUri, CropImageOptions())
                                        imageCropper.launch(
                                            cropOptions)
                                        viewModel.notLoadingCircleShown()

                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

When the useer is in the cropper, te app the texts if there is text or not:

```
val imageCropper = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    CropImageContract()
) { result ->
    imageInProcess.value = false
    if (result.isSuccessful) {

        val encodedUri = Uri.encode(
            result.uriContent!!
                .toString()
                .replace('%', '|')
        )
        val recognizer =
            TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS)

        val recognizedText = mutableStateOf("")

        val image = InputImage.fromFilePath(currentContext, result.uriContent!!)
        recognizer.process(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                recognizedText.value = it.text
                if (it.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                    navController.navigate(AppScreens.SecondScreenImage.route + "/$encodedUri" + "/${recognizedText.value}")
                } else {
                    viewModel.clickedNullImageButton()
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Log.e("TextCapture", "CropImageContract error: ")
                Toast.makeText(currentContext, "holalal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

    } else {
        val exception = result.error
        Log.e("CameraCapture", "CropImageContract error: ${exception?.message}")
    }
```

It is all going all right, but however, when I take a blurry photo, this error occurs and crashes the app : FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.app, PID: 28738
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException